# Why Seam conversation id (cid) does not go sequencial order

Tags: seam-conversation

I have a problem at seam conversation.

I know that conversation id works in sequencial order when i see at url bar (http://myprojectname/login.xhtml?cid=1). But in my program , I first begin conversation and cid is 1 (http://myprojectname/login.xhtml?cid=1) and then i begin nest conversation and cid becomes 4 (http://myprojectname/register.xhtml?cid=4). Why does it happen?

In successful program, cid is 1 after that cid is 2 and then 3, 4 for new nested conversation. But we wonder why conversation id becomes 1 and then 4.

Please explain me.

Answer (score 1):

There are different potential causes of your "problem". In your case, I suppose, `cid=1` and `cid=2` were temporary conversations, used by login-redirection, `cid=3` is long-running and `cid=4` is nested one.

In general, urls are not the best place to track conversation usage/management. Seam doesn't economize on cid's, the only thing which is guaranteed is that cid's always grow.

So, I would not worry about that..